# Set thread run speed (emulation of slower processors)

Tags: multithreading, avr

Is it possible to, when creating a new thread in a c++ program, set what will the run speed of the thread be? I want to emulate an avr, including it's clock frequency. And would like to know if there's some way to say to my thread like: "Hey, run this at 16MHz."
If there's no way to make this, would it be possible to use debug breakpoints, or another way of getting the same results? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No system I've ever programmed has that capability.

Comment: Your emulator code will have to have some sort of main loop where it starts the emulation of each operation. Simply put a timer in the loop. Or keep timestamps for each operation

Comment: Do you already know how to check the current time from your thread and tell your thread to go to sleep for some time?